# has_many/belongs_to association leads to double queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the code

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

I have something like the following in my code (given `params[:magazine_name]`, `params[:ad_name]`):

```
mag = Magazine.find_by_name(params[:magazine_name])
@ad = mag.ads.find_by_name(params[:ad_name])
```

If I now access `@ad.magazine`, it makes another database query finding by the magazine id, which is stored in `@ad`. Why isn't ActiveRecord smart enough to realize it's already gotten that from the database and it shouldn't it get it again? (And how do I make it smarter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not smart enough is because ActiveRecord doesn't use the identity map pattern by default. The solution is rumoured to be [using `:inverse_of` on your relationships](http://mediumexposure.com/better-memory-associations-inverseof/).

Comment: (Link: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4914-activerecord-inverse_of-doesnt-have-any-effect)

Comment: Looks like it'll be fixed in 3.1: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/04/21/activerecord-identity-map/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something called "eager loading", where you go ahead and load associations that you know you'll be needing soon.  The way to do this is different between Rails 2 and Rails 3.

In rails 3, you use the .includes method:

```
Ad.includes(:magazine).find_by_name(params[:ad_name])
```

In rails 2, you use the :include hash:

```
Ad.find_by_name(params[:ad_name], :include => [:magazine])
```

Comment: Whilst that's a good idea and reduces the number of queries from N+1 to 1, that's not actually what the OP was asking.

Comment: How does it not? He wants to be able to do @ad.magazine without generating a new database query, which is what this does.

Comment: But I already loaded the magazine before finding the ad; it should recognize this and recycle the reference.